Web scraping using Apify with load more button
I am trying to scrape news articles from the website here using Apify-Smart Article Extractor. However, the webpage contains a 'load more' button which needs to be clicked in order to reveal required articles which could be scraped further.
I am new to Apify and Smart Article Extractor. I am clueless as to how to handle this. Can someone please suggest some options.

You could try playing with the options under Browser options. I would suggest enabling Use browser and Scroll to bottom of the page. The description of Scroll to bottom button selector says "CSS selector for a button to load more articles": it seems like what you are looking for. A possible selector for the button could be:
li.pager__item > a.button


Hi @Marco Gullo - Thanks for your reply. I tried your solution but couldn't get it to work. It seems to be extracting articles which are available by default on the landing page but it doesn't seem to get the other articles which get available by clicking the "Load More" button. Just FYIP, I'm trying to extract articles starting from 2024-08-20 but it doesn't seem to work
